# Capturing output from standard io encoding?

Tags: c#, utf-8, character-encoding, redirectstandardoutput

I'm piping the output of an app into my .NET app.

The encoding is somewhat strange.
Letters ÅÄÖ shows up as ├Ñ ├ñ ├Â

I have tried to convert back and forth from various different encodings w/o any success.
Anyone know how the string should be converted correctly here?

e.g. the documentation for the app says the output is UTF8, so I've tried this:

```
byte[] encodedBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(theOutput);
var res = Encoding.Default.GetString(encodedBytes);
```

Which goves the incorrect result.

edit:
code:

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
   CreateNoWindow = true,
   RedirectStandardOutput = true,
   RedirectStandardInput = true,
   UseShellExecute = false,
   Arguments = a,
   FileName = path + "\\phantomjs.exe"
};

var process = new Process
{
   StartInfo = processStartInfo,
   EnableRaisingEvents = true
};

//capturing output here
process.OutputDataReceived += 
   (sender, args) => outputBuilder.Append(args.Data);

process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.WaitForExit(20000);
process.CancelOutputRead();
```

Comment: How are you obtaining this output to start with? Please give more context. Converting a string to bytes and back using a different encoding is almost *always* a bad idea.

Comment: @Mgetz: It may well be - but I'm waiting to find out. (Just making the other app write to a file would be a good way of controlling things...)

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, if I pipe the same command to a file, the output looks correct... e.g.  phantomjs.exe myscript.js > foo.txt

Comment: @RogerAlsing Appears correct HOW? What encoding does it have the file? If you try to open it with an "advanced" editor (Notepad++ for example), is the file recognized as ANSI or UTF-8?

Comment: And I see you are from Sweden... Do you know your codepage? You should be 1252 for Windows and 865 for DOS (could you try to launch `chcp` in a command prompt?)

Answer (score 15):

Found the solution.
You can set

```
   processStartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

This makes it output correctly.